# When I use angular to post data to server , 2 request (POST and OPTIONS Method) are sent

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner in the Angularjs. When I use angular to post data to server , 2 request  (POST and OPTIONS Method) are sent. Is it possible to send just 1 request?

I use and test it by  `$http` ,`$http.post` and `$resource` but it not resolved.

Thanks.

My code...

```
$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: myUrl,
          data: 'test'                    
      });
```

...this...

```
$http.post(myUrl ,'test data')
     .then(function(resp) {
         console.log('Success', resp);
     }, function(err) {
         console.error('ERR', err);
     });
```

...and:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
app.controller("HttpController", [ '$scope', '$resource',
    function($scope, $resource) {
        $scope.saveUser = function(){
            var User = $resource(myUrl);
            User.save( myData , function(response){
            // ....
        });
    }
}]);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that none of these is causing the issue, but a different binding ? If you remove the above options you mentions, is the `OPTIONS` request still generated?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your requests URLs are not visible on your screenshot. But I guess your backend is not running on the same origin as the frontend.
Therefore Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) needs to be done.

The HTTP Options call is automatically done by the browser in order to determine whether you have the permission to do the desired HTTP call. See [preflight requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example)

Answer (score 0):

So far I know OPTIONS method is used for identyfing if user has right for make a request (the next one, in your case POST, test1.php). In your response of OPTIONS request you should have allowed methods, allowed origin and few other stuff (here's a full explonation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). So answering to your question... as long as you're making requests from client side + request URI is not in your origin(domain) - CORS priciple always comes up -> you alwayts have to do OPTIONS request.